# iOS custom keyboard blur view as background

Tags: ios, keyboard, blur, uivisualeffectview

This is really simple, but maybe not easy?

I'm trying to build a custom keyboard app for iOS, and so far I've made a concept work pretty well. But I really want to have the whole container/background view to be a blur view (frosted glass effect built in iOS), much like the system keyboard. It's very subtle, but I really want that effect.

Any idea how to apply it? Help!

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found (which is great but not ideal) is to simply set the background color of the ViewController to transparent. By giving it a color with alpha = 0, it has the same color as the system keyboard background.

But this doesn't let you go any further in terms of transparency, so the blur is *very* subtle.